# Remove parts of pattern from string with gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a list of strings like this (58*5 cases omitted):

```
participant_01_Bullpup_1.xml
participant_01_Bullpup_2.xml
participant_01_Bullpup_3.xml
participant_01_Bullpup_4.xml
participant_01_Bullpup_5.xml
#...Through to...
participant_60_Bullpup_1.xml
participant_60_Bullpup_2.xml
participant_60_Bullpup_3.xml
participant_60_Bullpup_4.xml
participant_60_Bullpup_5.xml
```

I want to use gsub on these so that I end up with (example only):

```
01_1
60_5
```

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("part*.csv")

for (fileName in fileNames) {
    sample <- read.csv(fileName, header = FALSE, sep = ",")
    part   <- gsub("[^0-9]+", "", substring(fileName, 5, last = 1000000L))
    print(part)
}
```

This results in the following strings (example):

```
011
605
```

However, I can't work out how to keep a single underscore between these strings.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sub('[^0-9]+_([0-9]+_).*([0-9]+).*', '\\1\\2', str1)
#[1] "01_1"
```

---

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(str1, '\\d+'), paste, collapse='_')
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'participant_01_Bullpup_1.xml'
```

Comment: Sorry, do I place the sapply before the sub? The first bit of the script works like a wonder though

Comment: @MichaelAnderson  You don't need `sapply` before the `sub`.  You can do with the whole column i.e. `sub(...., yourdf$yourcolumn)`

Comment: `str_extract_all_regex()` may lead to better performance, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more options (using akrun's `str1`):

```
gsub("[^0-9_]+|(?<=\\D)_", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "01_1"
sub(".+?(\\d+_).+?(\\d+).+", "\\1\\2", str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "01_1"
sub(".+?(\\d+).+?(\\d+).+", "\\1_\\2", str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "01_1"
paste(strsplit(str1, "\\D+")[[1]][-1], collapse="_")
#[1] "01_1"
```

If your pattern really is that consistent (i.e. 12 characters before the first digits, followed by 8 characters until the next set of digits, followed by 4 more characters), then you can be explicit with your quantifiers:

```
sub(".{12}(\\d+_).{8}(\\d+).{4}", "\\1\\2", str1)
#[1] "01_1"
```

or simply access the characters use the appropriate indices:

```
paste0(substr(str1, 13, 15), substr(str1, 24, 24))
#[1] "01_1"
```